# gdb "step" does not step when debugging C

Tags: c, linux, gdb

I am running gdb on a rather simple C code in Linux environment. I set a break point and run. The  debugger stops at the breakpoint, but from there on, step does not seem to step forward and will stay on the same line (and does not execute the line either). I get the very same behavior when using netbeans while debugging.

Please see a link to a screenshot here:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/n03oacbhp3bh4r2/Capture.JPG

I realized, based on a comment below, when I disable the breakpoint after hitting it, and issue "step", things work as expected.

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Unless you provide something that can we can use to reproduce your problem, all you will get as a response is guesswork (from those willing to waste time in guessing).

Comment: Did you compile with `gcc -Wall -g` *all* the source files of your C code ? Show more of it, and how did you build it?

Comment: I added a link that takes you to a screen shot with all the details. Hopefully this helps.

Comment: From what I see in your link, what you're doing is correct, and should be working. Have you tried this without Netbeans? I'm guessing there's some strange interaction issue. Did you just write the code in a text editor, compile with gcc, and then run with gdb (no netbeans interactions?)

Comment: I tried to reproduce (without Netbeans) but it works as should for me..

Comment: @mike, There is no netbeans interaction in the image. It is all from the command line. If I debug using the netbeans IDE, it behaves the same; the highlighted line stays highlighted and does not proceed when I press F7.

Comment: Does the behavior change, when you disable the breakpoint after hitting it?

Comment: @harper You may be on to something. When I disable the breakpoint, and issue step, things will work as expected.

Comment: Code compiled with optimization acts weird (some lines aren't executed ever, variables just don't exist, execution jumps around, ...). It happens that there are several instructions on a line, and stepping forward just stays on it until leaving for the next one. Without debugging information, the debugger doesn't know where the source lines start and stop in the executable, so it can't step them.

Comment: I disable the optimization using -O0 option in gcc, but still does not make any difference.